# ¿Por qué es la palabra «mano» femenina?

Tags: etimología, género, latín

En español, tenemos una regla en la cual, generalmente, se puede tener fe: Si una palabra termina con -o, es masculina. Sin embargo, palabras que terminan en -e o -a también pueden ser palabras masculinas, pero una que termina con -o es masculina sin duda.

Existe la excepción en la palabra «mano». ¿Por qué es esto? ¿Cómo se originó esta excepción?

Comment: Hay varias más: la radio, la moto, la foto.

Comment: [this](http://www.tritrans.net/forumcgi/forum.cgi?msg=1476) suggests that it is because of the fact that the word "mano" originates from Latin "manus" which has a feminine form.

Comment: @dusan Las dos segundas son formas más cortas: la motocicleta, la fotografía. Me parece que la radio es la misma cosa, pero no estoy segura.

Comment: Although it's understood what is meant, i think the topic title is wrong. "La Mano" isn't a word.

Comment: @dusan: Those are all foreign words (and contractions). Could that have something to do with it? (E.g. La (foto)grafi?)

Comment: @TomAu: I think you are right. Even radio is a contraction (radiodifusión).

Comment: @AarthiDevanathan: Yes, I think la mano is the only natural feminine word ending in "o" in Spanish.  The rest are alternative forms, short forms, and other variations.

Comment: @Brian: "la dinamo" is also feminine in Spanish: http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=dinamo

Comment: @CesarGon Odd, in Mexico we say, "los dinamos."

Comment: @Brian: It's feminine according to DRAE, and in Spain I've always heard "la dinamo".

Comment: @CesarGon The Oxford Spanish Dictionary says: *dinamo m or (Esp) f* so apparently feminine dynamos are a usage peculiar to Spain. Nevertheless, Spanish in Spain is natural so it does constitute a natural example beyond *mano*.

Comment: @Brian: Fair enough.

Comment: @dusan me parece que la radio viene de radioreceptor (el aparato) para el cual debiera decirse el radio, y para la radioemisora si debiera decirse la radio.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero tienes razón. Según la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=radio), radio también puede venir de radiorreceptor, pero son acepciones diferentes de la palabra.

Comment: "dusan si , claro son dos acepciones diferentes. Son dos cosas diferentes. http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=radio

Comment: **libido** also ends in "o" and is also femenine

Comment: **ratio** is also femenine

Comment: Para complicar mas la cosa, en Argentina se utiliza el diminutivo "manito", femenino; la manito. En España sin embargo se utiliza "manita".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Gender

While the rule is *in general* that all -o words are masculine, there are exceptions. This one is one of these exceptions to that rule.

#### Origin

One theory ([proposed here](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/154655/why-is-la-mano-not-el-mano)) is that this word derived from the Latin word *manus* which was a fourth-declension feminine noun.  For comparison, first declension nouns were all feminine and second declension were all masculine or neuter.  This particular word, though, was a fourth-declension noun.

Fourth declension nouns were a bit different since they are predominantly masculine with some feminine exceptions.  "Manus" was one of those exceptions.

#### Summary

More than likely, the word la mano derived from the Latin word manus, which was feminine.

Comment: I like how you call it "a theory" when it seems pretty obvious to me that's exactly what happened. ;) (By the way, there were masculine first-declension nouns, like "athleta", and feminine second-declension nouns, like "humus" -- but the latter were quite rare.)

Comment: I remember reading about Latin *sogrus*, which must have been one of these nouns. It evolved analogically into *suegra* for obvious reasons. (Don't ask me what "father-in-law" was in Latin.)

Comment: @pablodf76 "father-in-law" was [*socer*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/socer#Latin) in Latin. Spanish *suegro* evolved expectedly from the singular accusitive *socrum*, which probably influenced why *socrus* became *suegr**a***.

Comment: @kefschecter All first declension masculine "occupation" nouns that survived into Spanish kept BOTH the -a ending AND the masculine gender (poeta, escriba, pirata, (astro)nauta, etc.).

Answer (score 9):

## 1. Why most nouns ending *-o* are masculine, and *-a* are feminine

Spanish is a Romance language, which means it is descended from Latin. In Latin, nouns fell into 5 groups, depending on how they were [declined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_declension) (i.e. how their suffixes changed depending on case).

The first declension nouns usually end in *-a* in the nominative singular and are mostly feminine, which is why most words ending *-a* are feminine in Spanish.

The second and fourth declension nouns usually end *-us* in the nominative singular and are mostly masculine. Latin words ending *-us* [generally evolved into](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/vowels.htm) words ending *-o* in Spanish, which is why most words ending *-o* are masculine in Spanish.

## 2. Why *mano* bucks the trend

*mano* comes from Latin *manus* - one of the few [**feminine** fourth declension nouns](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/101/Declension4.pdf), which explains why it ends *-o*.

However, even within these feminine 4th declension nouns, *manus* is an exception in Spanish, being the only one to both retain its feminine gender and its (morphologically) expected suffix:

**Changed gender**

- echo > [eco](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eco#Spanish) (m)
- porticus > [pórtico](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%B3rtico#Spanish) (m)
- īdūs (pl) > [idus](http://dle.rae.es/?w=idus) (m, pl)
- quīnquātrūs (pl) > quinquatro (m)<sup>2</sup>
- `lat` domus > `it` duomo > `fr` dôme > `es` [domo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/domo#Spanish) (m)

**Changed suffix**

- fagus > [materia] fāgea > faya > [haya](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haya#Spanish) (f)
- acus > *acūcula > *acūcla > [aguja](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aguja#Etymology) (f)
- socrus > *socra<sup>1</sup> > [suegra](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suegra#Spanish) (f)
- nurus > *nora > [nuera](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nuera#Spanish) (f)
- tribus > [tribu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tribu#Spanish) (f)

**Both**

- quercus > quernus > al quernus > al quernus + occus > [alcornoque](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alcornoque#Spanish) (m)

**Neither**

- manus > mano (f)

**The reason *mano* maintained both of these aspects is probably due to a combination of factors:**

- it didn't refer to a female person, and so had no semantic pressure to change (e.g. *nuera, suegra*)
- it was a very common word
- it didn't gain a diminutive suffix in its evolution
- it didn't refer to a tree<sup>3</sup>

---

**Notes**

<sup>**1.** "Father-in-law" was *socer* in Latin, which evolved expectedly from the singular accusitive *socrum* > **socro* > *suegro*, which may have also influenced *socrus* becoming *suegr**a***.</sup>

<sup>**2.** 1803 DLE.</sup>

<sup>**3.** In addition to the examples presented, fourth declension nouns referring to *trees* were feminine in Latin as well. These almost exclusively became masculine in Spanish, with the exception of the above *fagus > haya*:</sup>
<sup>• pinus > pino (m)

• taxus > tejo (m)

• alnus > [alno](http://dle.rae.es/?id=22CBqer) (m)

• prunus > [pruno](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UVc6yb1) (m)

• populus > *plōppus > [pobo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TSTcTYw), [chopo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chopo#Spanish) (m) etc</sup>