# What is the significance of the gender of a noun in Spanish?

Tags: etimología, género

I'm just relying on memorization to conjure the gender of nouns. Perhaps if I understood etymologically why these genders came about, I would have an easier time remembering. There are three perplexities that I would like to demonstrate with some example words:

1. **Original Formation.** What traits make an object masculine or feminine? "El sonido" does not have sexual organs. Sound is not even visible. So why did the creators of Spanish choose "el sonido" instead of "la sonida"?
2. **Special Rules.** If it ends in *-a*, it is feminine. If it ends in most other letters, it is masculine. However, if it ends in *-dad* or *-ción*, it is feminine. What's the rhyme or reason for adding *-dad* and *-ción* rules? Why couldn't "la ciudad"  just be "el ciudad" for simplicity?
3. **Irregularities.** Why is "idioma" masculine and "mano" feminine? Language can be spoken by either gender and hands also belong to creatures of both genders. I have a feeling that there may be a cultural or historical reason why some nouns became irregular in gender.

Comment: English speaker complaining of irregularities. Doesn't get more ironic than that ;-)

Comment: btw. this is gonna blow your brains: *"la gente"*

Comment: @vartec Your opinion is an Ad Hominem attack. English does not use gender on objects that have no sexual organs. Therefore, there does not exist any irregularities in gender in English. Thus, my so called "complaining" is justified because this concept does not exist in my native tongue.

Comment: it's true that you come from disadvantaged position of speaking the only European language, which has lost the [grammatical concept of gender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender). I do believe however, that concept of irony does exist in English :-P English is highly irregular, in fact it probably the most irregular language that exists. Of course it's not about gender, but about spelling, verb conjugation, etc. In English there are more words that don't follow any rule, than these that do.  Just take a look at list of irregular verbs in English.

Comment: I never denied the existence of irregularities in English. Since we are on the topic of gender, I spoke of gender. Whereas you chose to veer off topic and poke fun at my mother language. My question only asked how gendered words were created in Spanish. I never said it was a stupid idea, which you made it out to be by labeling my questioning as "complaining".

Comment: I think this is far too broad for a single question.  You have 4 or 5 distinct questions here. Many of them are very good questions, but need to be asked separately (some of them [have](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32/12)). I encourage you to focus on one specific aspect per question; and by all means, ask as many questions as you like!

Comment: There is one case where English is *less* ambiguous than Spanish WRT genders, and that is the third person pronouns.  Spanish uses only "su", where English uses "his" or "hers". It's one case where I can get back at my Spanish speaking friends for teasing me when I make gender mistakes... when they say "his" when they mean "hers"...

Comment: @JoJo: English sometimes does use gender on objects with no sexual organs.  "She sure is a beautiful ship!"

Comment: From what I understand, there is a masculinity and femininity to everything in other languages.  El sol is masculine compared to la luna that is much less bright, and smaller in comparison.  La manzana would be the smaller, and el manzano (apple tree) would be the larger and masculine.  Looking at your example of el sonido, would be larger, and more general, whereas, something like la musica, would have a beautiful and more delicate quality, making it more of a feminine construction.  I wouldn't say that it is a rule that anything that doesn't end with 'a' it is masculine, its just the rules.

Comment: Yes I agree with Flimzy there are multiple questions here. You should make as many questions as you need to resolve all your doubts, not make a list-like question if you can avoid it. In my personal opinion I don't think this will help you identify the differences in gender of the different nouns. And about the original formation it is unlikely a reason will be found. You call them irregularities but that's only because you don't yet fully understand how they work. That is normal. Every language has exceptions, but there aren't that many in spanish. Try to get the flow of the language.

Answer (score 5):

May I adopt a pessimistic approach? Partial answer: it could be worse.

1. The *creators of Spanish* doesn't seem to be a valid expression: Spanish, as any 
   language, evolved — and evolves! Moreover, the fact that sex concides with gender should be rather seen as a happy coincidence. Some time ago, one said *la ingeniero*, for women engineers. In German, for instance, that doesn't even happens: one has *das Mädchen* (la niña), which in Spanish is gendered, but in German isn't: it's neutral. Same case for *das Kind* (el niño).
2. (and 3.) Every language has exceptions (English has no *gender* exceptions, because it doesn't have gender). One has to deal with it, and it shouldn't be hard: Spanish  possesses the next to simplest gender structure. Believe me, the rules of the endings are regular enough, so I'd just enjoy this feature (by the way I don't know if there is a gendered language so regular: French isn't, but perhaps Italian, Portuguese or Romanian are. In order to learn other langugages which have two genders, say Dutch, you have to learn which nouns are neutral (with *het* article) and which have a gender (article *de*): all that without a far reaching rule, as the *-a* ending-rule in Spanish !

Comment: I'd like to add: genders come mostly from latin, and they were not regular there. So no latin language that I know of is perfectly regular between  word endings and gender.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I think you are mixing two different concepts. The English word *gender* does not always translate as *género*. In Spanish, *género* is a grammar category, while living organisms have *sexo*. Nowadays you can read or hear the word *género* used for the second meaning due to English influence, but it is incorrect. Sure, most words denoting male humans are masculine and those denoting female humans are feminine, but even here there are exceptions.

Etimology would not be of much use here. Gender is not always kept when a word evolves. Thus, the Spanish word *leche* (*milk*) is feminine, while its Portuguese counterpart, *leite*, which comes from the same Latin word, is masculine. And don't try to make out gender from *masculine* or *feminine* characteristics in inanimate objects. It is not difficult to find synonyms with different gender, even for animals (*leopardo* is masculine, while *pantera* is feminine, and they are both the same animal).

So the best you can do is stick on word terminations to give you a hint on gender and learn the exceptions. This is unfortunate, if you want, but there is nothing much better to do.